# Remove First Image in All WordPress Posts?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Is there a way through a SQL script that I can run that will delete the first image of all posts? We moved to a new theme and now the featured image and the image at the top of the post replicate each other. I want to use the featured image, but would rather not go back through 2000+ posts and delete the top image. So...any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You're going to have to show the raw data of a sample post. There's no hierarchical structure that a DELETE can do here. The post content is stored in raw form in the wp_posts table in the post_content field. The change will take an update with string manipulation of your html to remove the specific html from matching posts

Comment: My suggestion is to change the theme it self. Find the place where images are displayed and remove one. If you are using some commercial theme then maybe it's a good idea to make new theme by inheriting commercial one and to override just those templates containing image elements.